# A concave function on a compact and convex set is upper semi continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

Let $X$ be a compact and convex set and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a concave function. Therefore, $f$ is continuous on interior of $X$. I want to know whether $f$ is upper semi continuous on $X$. If not, under which (minimum) assumption is?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is wrong in many cases. E.g. if you define $f(x) = 1$ in the interior of $X$ and $f(x) = 0$ on the boundary then $f$ is concave and lower semi-continuous, but not upper semi-continuous. Do you have any example where this is true (and $f$ is not continuous on the boundary)? –  Or did you mean a *convex* function?

Comment: Also, the continuity on the interior of $X$ works only if $f$ is locally bounded on the interior of $X$ (there are even linear functions that are nowhere continuous).